# DC Power Jack for ASUS K501UX

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair, repair, power-jack

I've been searching for a replacement power jack for my ASUS K501UX laptop.

[This take-apart video](https://www.clipzui.com/video/n413b5k3s3d51443f4x5s4.html) is quite helpful, but I've not been able to find the replacement part that I need. [This part](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA7255XW4324) was supposed to be compatible, but once I got my laptop taken apart I realized that it wasn't what I needed. The cords coming out the back are useless, as I need something that I can solder in.

[Here's a picture of the part](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMlERPuVpNEQuRNw4eZk1RhyV-sJSPPcbCYwnzZ6svVctKg26mdrok5GSzPhD-wOA?key=eEZ0Vl9LTzRzTnhtTjUwQ2I3QkpJSHp1Y0lqUnN3), complete with a serial number, 150921+1.
[This part](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIABG35G41676) looks closer to what I need, but the models listed don't match mine.

Any tips on where I can find a part that's compatible? I've tried contacting ASUS support, but they had no recommendations.

Comment: The view that you provided of your existing jack is useless. We need to see the top, bottom and front views to match the jack. Have you looked on eBay? There should be zero problems finding the jack you need on there. I have bought hundreds of jacks from dcpowerjacks.net. If they don’t have it, it doesn’t exist. However, I’ve been out of the business for a while and their website isn’t currently responding so I’m not sure if it is temporary or if they closed up shop. Ebay has all this stuff though. In general I have no problem finding the jack by simply searching for ‘Asus k501ux power jack’.

Comment: Good call, @Appleoddity. One Ebay search and there it was. https://www.ebay.com/itm/Asus-K501U-K501UB-K501UQ-K501UX-K501UW-Series-DC-Jack-Power-Socket-Connector/281941984682?hash=item41a50d45aa:g:KbUAAOSwnTxZbK2-